# Клавиши курсора и поиск по истории команд не работают в SQL*Plus и RMAN

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Часто приходится пользоваться в консоли SQL*Plus и RMAN для администрации БД.
В консоли настроен *readline* для быстрого перемещения курсора в строке ввода и поиска по истории выполненых команд.

Но если запустить в консоли SQL*Plus, то клавиши курсора не работают, например стрелка-влево:

```
SQL> select ffiel^[[D
```

Соответственно, нет возможности выполнить передвижение и поиск по истори команд.

Как можно решить проблему?

Answer (score 2):

Командная строка SQL*Plus и других инструментов не использует *readline*. В этом случае следует воспользоваться утилитой [rlwrap](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rlwrap) (*readline wrapper*).

> **DESCRIPTION**
>   rlwrap runs the specified command, intercepting user input in order to provide readline's line editing, persistent history and completion.

Она уже включена в большинство дистрибутивов *Linux* и может быть установленна доступным в них менеджером пакетов, например:

```
apt-get install rlwrap
```

Также, можно установить [вручную с GitHub](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap). После установки надо маскировать вызов оригинальных программ, например, добавив в конфигурационные файлы оболочки консоли:

```
alias sqlplus='rlwrap sqlplus'
alias rman='rlwrap rman'
```

Теперь клавиши курсора будут выполнять функции настроенные в файле ~/.inputrc.

Answer (score 2):

Поведение аналогичное *readline* [было предложено ввести](https://community.oracle.com/ideas/5140) для командной строки в SQL*Plus.

Начиная с версии 12.2 доступна команда [HIST[ORY]](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqpug/HISTORY.html#GUID-CCF9B047-3122-4644-BA06-5FA4B5812E9F). Но как и попрежде, клавишы курсора недоступны и `rlwrap` остаётся предпочтительным решением.

Чем же может быть полезна новая команда по сравнению с `rlwrap`. Поиск и редактирование многострочных SQL запросов было и остаётся с `rlwrap` сложной задачей, т.к. он запоминает историю ввода построчно. Команда `HIST[ORY]` позволит найти в истории выполненый ранее сложный запрос, отредактировать его в редакторе указанным в переменной окружения `EDITOR`, и сохранить в истории.

```
SQL> set hist on
SQL> select 1
  2  from dual;

SQL> select 1
--      ^--здесь нажата <C-Up> - rlwrap дополнил из истории только 1 строку 
SQL> hist
  1  select 1
     from dual;

SQL> hist 1 edit

SQL> hist
  1  select 1
     from dual;
  2  select 2
     from dual;
```

Comment: Интересно появилось ли что-то новенькое в модном SQLcl? :)